# Laravel resource match in blade

Tags: php, laravel, routes, wildcard, laravel-5.8

I have build a typical crud system using laravel(5.8) resource routing.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

I'm trying to match any methods of that resource to make the link shows active in menu:

```
  <li class="nav-item 
      @if(Request::route()->getName() == 'users.index' 
        || Request::route()->getName() == 'users.create'
        || Request::route()->getName() == 'users.show'
        || Request::route()->getName() == 'users.*.edit') 
       active
      @endif">
       <a href="#">Users</a>
  </li>
```

Is there a clear solution for this?

Comment: There's something like `Route::is('users.*`)` you can look into. Don't quite have the exact syntax on the top of my head.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve this.

```
<li class="nav-item {{ str_is('users.*', Route::currentRouteName()) ? 'active' : '' }}>
  <a href="#">Users</a>
</li>
```

This uses the [str_is()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-is) laravel helper to see if the string contains `users.`. This is check against the current route's name.

It then outputs `active` if true and nothing if false.

**Note:** In Laravel 5.8, string and array helpers have been removed by default. Your code will need to use the `Str` facade.

```
<li class="nav-item {{ \Str::is('users.*', Route::currentRouteName()) ? 'active' : '' }}>
  <a href="#">Users</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way i found in laravel for multiple routs is this
this way it will match all route like roles.index roles.create roles.* and users.*

```
class="{{ str_contains(Route::currentRouteName(), ['roles','users']) ? 'active' : '' }}"
```